# Can Phabricator ignore Ref Txxx in commits for a particular branch?

Tags: git, phabricator

We use the `Ref Txxx`syntax in our git commits to link those to *phabricator* tasks. Nice feature, exactly what we want, however:

During development and rebasing in a **particular branch** this creates a lot of noise in the *phabricator* history, i.e. a lot of commits are shown as striketrough after a rebase etc.

[image: phabricator striketrough]

Can this be avoided? Of course, I could use a dummy `Ref` and then replace those when I think I am done. But can I exclude a branch from being monitored by *phabricator* or is there another smart way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have phabricator just watch certain ones, and thereby implicitly ignore other branches.

Go to `Repositories` -> select a repository -> Actions -> Manage Repository -> Branches-> Edit. Here you can set `Track Only` to describe which branches phabricator should look at.

I've got a number of branches where I want phabricator to ignore `personal/$USER/` branches, thus I set `Track Only`to:

```
regexp(/^(?!personal)/)
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/diffusion_managing/#branches).

Answer (score 1):

Anders' answer was unsatisfactory for our needs, as excluding a branch from being tracked means that Phabricator can not see it at all, so the branch can not be browsed in Diffusion, which makes it impossible to do code review with inline comments. What we want to do is just prevent `Ref Txxx` from taking effect when it occurs in branches matching a specified pattern.

It turns out that this is exactly what **Autoclose** does. The documentation doesn't say it, and the name doesn't imply it, but `Ref Txxx` only takes effect in branches which have Autoclose enabled. The documentation only says that Autoclose controls whether things like `Closes Txxx` can automatically change the status of a task.

Browse to your repository in Diffusion and select <kbd>≡ Actions</kbd>⇾<kbd>Manage repository</kbd>⇾<kbd>Branches</kbd>⇾<kbd>Edit</kbd>.

Suppose you want to disable `Ref` links in `feature/*` branches. Set "Autoclose Only" to:

```
regexp(/^(?!feature\/)/)
```

(Note the use of `\/` to escape the `/` which would otherwise be treated as the end of the regex.)

It's a list, and a branch is enabled if it matches any one or more of the patterns, so suppose you wanted to enable `Ref` links for `master`, `release/*`, and `develop/*` branches and disable them in all other branches. You would set "Autoclose Only" to:

```
master
regexp(/^release\//)
regexp(/^develop\//)
```